# How to make git recognize that I deleted a file?

Tags: git, github

I am getting this error,

```
File bigFile.txt is 125.61 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

This was after adding, committing, and trying to push. I went ahead and removed the `bigFile.txt` but the error keeps appearing every time I try to push again. I even tried undoing the last commit and it didn't work.

Comment: How did you "undo the last commit"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-commit

Comment: The answer below nor the answer in the question marked as 'duplicate' worked for me. What worked was saving all my files to another directory, running ` git reset --hard origin/master`, deleting the files in the git directory, and putting the saved files in the now empty git directory.

Comment: What you're describing is equivalent to `git reset --soft origin/master`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your last commit is the one with bigFile.txt, do the following:

```
git rm bigFile.txt
git commit --amend
```

This will alter your last commit to not have bigFile.txt in it.